# Chrome Extension: Appending elements to newly injected element not immediately appearing in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm writing a Chrome extension, and the functionality in question is from a content script, and is called when any element is right clicked and a context menu item is selected.  The function:

**--When an element is right-clicked--**

1. Creates a `<div>`
2. Applies the jQuery UI dialog widget to the `<div>`
3. Injects a HTML file, that contains a `<select>` element, to the `<div>`
4. Parses all the properties (tag, attributes, etc) from the selected element and compiles `<option>` elements from the properties.
5. Writes the `<option>` elements to the `<select>` element.

**--Then after the context menu is selected--**

6. Finally, when the context menu item is selected, the dialog box appears, containing the select element with the options.

The HTML file is pretty basic, so I left that out of my code below for brevity.

**The problem** is that when an element is right-clicked for the first time, everything but step 5 works, but then it works the second time.  Then every subsequent right-click works just fine - regardless of the element.

**Here's the code:**

```
var GTFA_ELE = {};
var GTFA_DIALOG_FLAG = false;

$(document).on('contextmenu',function(event){
    GTFA_ELE = {};
    //Check if the dialog has been created yet, if not, make it:
    if(!GTFA_DIALOG_FLAG){
        var dialogEle = document.createElement("div");
        dialogEle.id = "gtfa_dialog";

        //Inject the HTML for the rule form:
        $.get(chrome.extension.getURL('inject.html'), function(data) {
            $(data).appendTo(dialogEle);
        });
        //Commit the dialog box modal to dom:
        document.body.appendChild(dialogEle);

        //Apply the modal widget:
        $(function() {
            $( "#gtfa_dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            });
        });
        GTFA_DIALOG_FLAG = true;
    }

    GTFA_ELE = {};
    //Get info from the clicked element:
    var ele = $(event.target);

    //Get all the attributes:
    $(ele[0].attributes).each(function() {
        //Handle multiple classes differently:
        if(this.nodeName == "class" && this.nodeValue.indexOf(" ") > 0){
            //Split the string of classes into an array:
            var classes = this.value.split(" ");
            GTFA_ELE["classes"] = classes;
        } else {
            GTFA_ELE[this.nodeName] = this.value;
        }
    });
    //Get the tag name and the html of the selected element. These won't be added by the loop below, because they aren't attributes:
    GTFA_ELE.tag = event.target.tagName;
    GTFA_ELE.html = ele.html();

    var output_html = "";
    //Create the <option> elements from the available selectors (tag, id, class, href, etc...):
    $.each(GTFA_ELE, function(key, item) {
        if(key == "classes"){
            class_list = "";
            for(i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
                class_list += "<option>"+item[i]+"</option>";
            }
            output_html += "<option>Class...</option>";
        } else {
            output_html += "<option>"+key+": "+item+"</option>";
        }
    });
    $("#GTFA_ruleForm_url").val(GTFA_ELE.tag);

    //Inject the option elements created earlier:
    $( "#GTFA_ruleForm_selector" ).html(output_html);
});

//Handle message from background.js (context menu item is selected):
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.type == "open_rule"){
        $( "#gtfa_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      //sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
  });
```

Sorry if my explanation sucks, let me know if there is anything I can add.  I omitted a lot because it is largely unrelated and wouldn't help any beyond offering some more context.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic misunderstanding of the use of callbacks. In fact, step (4) and (5) don't work correctly on the first time because the `$.get` request hasn't yet completed so (3) hasn't happened when (4) and (5) are attempted.

I suggest reading up about proper use of callbacks and asynchronous javascript.

Then I would put (4) and (5) in their own function and call it both after (3) inside the `$.get` callback and in an `else` block after the `if(!GTFA_DIALOG_FLAG){` block.